# Why is R not reading a specific text file when it can read others in the same directory?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, readr

When I try to import a text file, Ratings.timed.txt, R says that the input file is ypu and that the data frame is just a long column of undefined, even though I can open and read it just fine. Do you know how I can fix it?

[This is what I'm talking about, for clarity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/272PT.png)

Edit: I was able to read the file using `Ratings.timed <- read.delim("Ratings.timed.txt", fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your file it is not really CSV (comma separated) but probably TSV (tab-separated). Because of that, you should rather use `read_tsv()` function.

Moreover, the file has probably BOM so the first column will get 3 extra symbols at the beginning of the name of the first column. I don't know any better with tidyverse than using `rename()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

read_tsv('filename.csv') %>%
  rename(userid.ID = colnames(.)[1])
```

Comment: Oh, thank you!

I'm going to edit the post, but I was also able to read the file using 


`Ratings.timed <- read.delim("Ratings.timed.txt", fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")`